# PLACEHOLDER - CoreDump, a macOS desktop SE client

Tags: app, placeholder

What the app will do: a macOS desktop client app for SE network sites with a clean user interface and potentially some features enhancing the regular SE web-based experience. Written in SwiftUI.

The app is currently in development.

Edit: I've made some progress with development of the app. Here is a screenshot of what the app window currently looks like:

[image]